# JavaScript textbox focus() in saved browser password with watermark/background text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, passwords

When user have saved e-mail/password for the website in browser saved passwords, starts typing his e-mail and then clicks the suggestion. The e-mail/password fields should be correctly filled.

The problem is: the password isn't being correctly filled at first, it shows "password" (plain text, the watermark value) and the text is selected (like a TAB when switching to a non-empty field).

But, for example, if you press a keyboard arrow to move cursor and it de-selects "password", the the correct saved password is there, in ******* format.

The focus() event is fired when user clicks his e-mail and password field is automatically selected, but i can't figure out how to solve this, i tried to simulate a click on password field to de-select "password", move cursor position inside the textbox but none worked.

This approach has a small flaw: if user has password "password" it will become visible on blur. You can avoid this by using a space (ie. "Insert password").

Here's the code:

```
$('input[id^="txtLoginPassword"]').each(function () {
this.value = $(this).attr('title');
$(this).addClass('text-label'); //text-label, text-label2 change color only
$(this).focus(function () {
    if (this.value == $(this).attr('title')) {
        $(this).removeClass('text-label');
        $(this).addClass('text-label2');
      }
});

$(this).keydown(function () {
    if (this.value == $(this).attr('title')) {
        this.value = '';
        $(this).removeClass('text-label2');
        if ($(this).attr('title').indexOf("password") >= 0) { $(this).attr('Type', 'password'); }
    }
});
$(this).blur(function () {
    if ((this.value == '') || (this.value == $(this).attr('title'))) {
        this.value = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).removeClass('text-label2');
        $(this).addClass('text-label');
        if ($(this).attr('title').indexOf("password") >= 0) { $(this).removeAttr('Type'); }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: How about using the `placeholder` attribute instead ?

Comment: It's a possibility, but i will be limited to its functionality. For example, placeholder disappear as soon as people click on the textbox. In my example, it fades on click and disdappear on type.